# Open web browser on launch of App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I need to know how to have an iphone app do nothing but open the web browser as soon as it starts.  I know the code needed to open a broswer.. its

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

My problem is I don't know where to put this code.  Ive tried putting it in main.m but it either errors or does nothing.  I'd like to avoid needing to use a button.  I'd prefer it be automatic as soon as the app is launched.  I also need to image this to a HDMI TV and once again, I know the code for this.. I just don't know where it should be put, as I also want it to begin as soon as the app is started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to submit this app to the App Store I've got bad news for you, Apple will reject your app if all it does is open a website.

But back to your question place the code in app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Comment: No, this is simply for demo purposes for a website.  Thanks for your help!